# How to pass data from one view to some other view in MVC 4.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to pass data from one view to another in MVC 4.0. I am new to MVC 4.0.
The scenario is that I have a View in which a combo box is populated when the view gets loaded. I have a form on this view and on submission of this form I need to do some processing and accordingly show some status message on the View.

Since HTTP is stateless protocol the data (with which combo box got populated) gets lost. I want to retain this data as I don't want to do same processing again and again to fetch the data.
Please suggest me how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC (although I don't think exclusively) you can use the `Session` class to store variables across multiple views.

You can add an object to the `Session` array as a key/value pair with `Session.Add()`, and you can access the data via either an index, or the key.

You can also add a variable by simply accessing the `Session` index with either the index or the key, regardless of whether you've explicitly added it to the array. So you can do `Session[0] = new Object();` or `Session["object"] = new Object();` because they have overridden the accessor property.

I would recommend however that you do some research into proper use of the `Session` array.

Comment: @user1966824 How _large_ is large? `Session` is all server-side, so it should be able to handle it.